resize2fs wont grow an mdadm array (raid6, lvm, ext4)
I've decided to grow my raid6 array:
- from: 7x 2TB drives (giving usable space of ~9TB in ext4/raid6)
- to:   7x 4TB drives (giving usable space of ~18TB in ext4/raid6)

I have replaced all seven drives, and they all contain the following structure and have been cleanly added to the array.
sda                                3.6T
└─sda1         linux_raid_member   3.6T
  └─md0        LVM2_member        18.2T
    └─shared-c ext4                9.1T /shared
sdb                                3.6T
└─sdb1         linux_raid_member   3.6T
  └─md0        LVM2_member        18.2T
    └─shared-c ext4                9.1T /shared
sdc                                3.6T
└─sdc1         linux_raid_member   3.6T
  └─md0        LVM2_member        18.2T
    └─shared-c ext4                9.1T /shared

.. continues thru to sdg in same way ... 

Then, I ran the grow command on the array, which expanded it to the size I was expecting:
// command I ran:
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max

// output from mdadm --detail /dev/md0 after grow command

/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun May 15 08:22:07 2016
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 19535080000 (18.19 TiB 20.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 3907016000 (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 7
     Total Devices : 7
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Tue Jun 11 01:26:08 2024
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 7
   Working Devices : 7
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Next I tried resizing the file system, using resize2fs using the following command:
resize2fs /dev/mapper/shared-c

But it said there was nothing to do - My guess is that it isn't recognising the additional space in the array. I've since done some research that suggests I should be doing something with the physical volume and logical volumes, but no free space is being shown in there either...
// output of pvdisplay

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md0
  VG Name               shared
  PV Size               9.07 TiB / not usable <5.38 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               64.00 MiB
  Total PE              148681
  Free PE               160
  Allocated PE          148521
  PV UUID               7wxoRZ-LhVL-3WV5-pRcs-LT9q-r0Em-KHClad

// output of lvdisplay

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/shared/c
  LV Name                c
  VG Name                shared
  LV UUID                IR9ohg-TWPk-loPX-OcVg-vajS-hSb9-eubJMa
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ,
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <9.07 TiB
  Current LE             148521
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     1280
  Block device           253:0

I'm not sure what the next step is in this process now - part of me thinks I should be doing a pvresize but the output of that is only showing 5.38mb of unused space, whereas I would assume the number should be in the TB territory for pvresize to work.
The array is currently working and all files in the array are intact and fine - Ideally I'd like to keep it that way.

Decided to put my big boy pants on, grit my teeth and push forward.
If your system is using LVM, I recommend a primer on LVM because it will make things somewhat clearer: https://www.techtarget.com/searchdatacenter/definition/logical-volume-management-LVM
This answer also helped a lot:
https://serverfault.com/questions/695902/extending-lvm-volume-groups-with-physical-extents-pvresize
pvdisplay was showing this...
  // output of pvdisplay

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md0
  VG Name               shared
  PV Size               9.07 TiB / not usable <5.38 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               64.00 MiB
  Total PE              148681
  Free PE               160
  Allocated PE          148521
  PV UUID               7wxoRZ-LhVL-3WV5-pRcs-LT9q-r0Em-KHClad

however lvmdiskscan was showing this...
  // output of lvmdiskscan -l

  WARNING: only considering LVM devices
  /dev/md0    [      18.19 TiB] LVM physical volume
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume

This told me that the underlying partitions were reporting the full capacity to LVM, but the [LVM] physical volume (sitting on /dev/md0) wasn't taking up the available amount of room.
So the next steps were:
// to expand the physical volume from ~9.1TB to ~18TB and 
// give the extra room to the volume group (VG: shared) automatically

pvresize /dev/md0 

// to expand the logical volume itself...
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/shared/c 

// to run a check on the filesystem 
// note: if you're not sure that your filesystem is clean, omit the -y argument

e2fsck -f -y /dev/mapper/shared-c

// and finally, to expand the ext4 at the top layer.
resize2fs /dev/mapper/shared-c

Mounted, all data present and expanded successfully. Very stressful process, but lots of learning. I hope this helps people in the future.
